# How do I format more complex text blocks before sending to the clipboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to set some text to a clipboard from flutter to paste in other apps. This of course is extremely simple with the following code:

```
void handleClipboard(NoteModel note) {
  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: note.note!));
}
```

However I would like to make another call to retrieve a Youtube URL with a seek position to be included in the text so when the user pastes into Discord for example, the text from the note will be placed in a readable manner while the Youtube video thumbnail is below waiting to be selected. For example something like below. I am sure this is most likely simple to do but this is my first time doing this with an app and I would like to learn the best way.

Thank you.

[image]

***Update with my solution***

```
getNoteResource([String? comment]) {
   final _url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";

  String note = _data.note!;
  String sourceId = _data.sourceId!;
  String playPosition = _data.mediaPlayPosition.toString();
  String timeType = "s";

  String url = "$_url$sourceId&t=$playPosition$timeType";

  if (comment != null) {
    return "$comment \r\n \r\n $note \r\n $url";
  }

  return "$note \r\n $url";
}
```

Comment: Do you already have the code to retrieve "Youtube URL with a seek position"?

Comment: Yes I do, its basically a note model. I updated the question with my solution. Was just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: I am not actually sure if this will work with all Youtube id's I tried to find a way to retrieve a url from the Youtube API to make sure I was using a valid url but I could not find anything in the API spec. I feel like my solution is kinda elementary since I am very new to flutter.